# Power BI visualization format Pane text title has no tedt title input box

Tags: powerbi

I get the format pane for a  visualization but the text title is gray and no input box for a text title opens

Comment: Please improve your question by showing the steps and some images of what your try to achieve and where it goes wrong.

Comment: Hit paint roller select text title from format pane but no  way to enter new text title am I stuck in some wrong mode?

Comment: Is this because he vidualisation has no data fields specified yet?

Comment: What is the visual name you are working with?

Comment: In order to be able to configure the "formatting" the visual must not be empty, put at leas on field in it.